# Wrap jquery lightbox in reusable angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to wrap a customized jquery lightbox in an angular directive. I don't want to touch the jquery code, because that's also used in non-angular projects, but I'd like to offer a nice Angular directive that makes using it a lot easier.

After working on it for a bit, I realized I probably want something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="job in ctrl.jobs" ng-click="lightbox.open()">
    <lightbox-popup api="lightbox" popup-condition="job.status == 'pending'" popup-options="{buttons: {confirm:'OK',cancel:'cancel'}}">
        <custom-popup-content data="job"/>
    </lightbox-popup>
    <td ng-repeat="tableColumn in ctrl.columnNames">{{ job[tableColumn] }} </td>
</tr>
```

Some issues here are that the ng-click needs to call a function in the lightbox (which has been solved), pass some configuration to the lightbox through isolate scope, and pass a condition when this lightbox has to work (only for pending jobs). Weirdly, that popup-condition does not end up in the lightbox's link function. The entire `job` property doesn't exist anymore by that time. Perhaps because a new isolate scope has been created in the mean time? But I should be able to pass `job` on like this, shouldn't I?

(I don't have a working plnkr yet, because I have to anonymize a lot of code, and at some point even the things I do have working stop working.)

The lightbox directive looks somewhat like this:

```
app.directive('lightboxPopup', function ($compile) {
    var box = require('fg/lightbox'); // this is our custom jquery lightbox

    var defaultSettings = {
        title: 'Popup title',
        buttons: {
            confirm: 'OK'
        }};

    return {
        scope: {
            popupCondition: '=',
            popupOptions: '=',
            api: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            function openLightbox() {
                console.log("popupOptions: ",scope.popupOptions); // works
                console.log("popupCondition: ",scope.popupCondition); // false, because job mysteriously doesn't exist
                if (scope.popupCondition === true) {
                    var settings = angular.extend(defaultSettings, scope.popupOptions);
                    console.log("settings: ",settings);
                    element.bind('click', function () {
                        var popup = box(settings).setHtml(element).open();
                    });
                }
            }
            scope.api = {
                open: openLightbox
            };

        }
    };
});
```

I hope someone has an idea why my popupCondition doesn't work anymore.

(It used to work in a much uglier version of my code, which made use of `var el = $compile( "<"+scope.popupDirective+"></"+scope.popupDirective+">" )( scope );`, which kind of works, but I find this really ugly.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I went with the ugly approach. I'm still looking for a nicer way to do this, but this code works:

```
app.directive('lightboxPopup', function ($compile) {
    var box = require('fg/lightbox'); // our custom jquery lightbox

    var defaultSettings = {
        title: 'Popup',
        buttons: {
            confirm: 'OK'
        }};

    var directiveSettings = {};

    function lightboxSettings(settings) {
        directiveSettings = settings;
    }

    return {
        scope: {
            popupCondition: '=',
            popupDirective: '@lightboxPopup',
            popupData: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.popupCondition === true) {
                scope[attrs.popupData] = scope.popupData;
                scope.lightboxSettings = lightboxSettings;
                var el = $compile( "<"+scope.popupDirective+"></"+scope.popupDirective+">" )( scope );
                element.bind('click', function () {
                    var settings = angular.extend(defaultSettings, directiveSettings, scope.popupOptions);
                    var popup = box(settings).setHtml(el).open();
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

The juggling with scopes and data to ensure the directive with the content for the popup has access to the data it needs, and can access the api from this directive to register its own callbacks, is pretty horrible in my opinion. But it works.

```
<tr ng-repeat="job in ctrl.jobs" lightbox-popup="popup-content-directive" popup-condition="job.status == 'pending'" popup-data="job">
    <td ng-repeat="tableColumn in ctrl.columnNames">{{ job[tableColumn] }} </td>
</tr>
```

The included directive with the content registers its lightbox configuration like this:

```
app.directive('popupContentDirective', function (updateService) {

    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.lightboxSettings({
                title: "Update job",
                buttons: {
                    cancel: "cancel",
                    confirm: "OK"
                },
                confirm: function() {
                    updateService.update(scope.job);
                }
            });
        },
        templateUrl: 'partials/popupContentDirective.html'
    };
});
```

The settings can also be overridden from the view. All in all, the functionality is what I want, but I think there should be a cleaner and prettier way to do this, so please post a better answer if you've got one.